# Cannot launch 2 realsense camera D435 on one pc (Solved )

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use two realsense camera D435 on one pc and I am using a usb3.0 hub but I am getting this error, Knowing that I have updated the firmware of the cameras and I am using ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic  :

```
[ERROR] [1540797812.593350082]: An exception has been thrown: xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed Last Error: Device or resource busy
[FATAL] [1540797812.714744205]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera1/realsense2_camera` of type `realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory` to manager `realsense2_camera_manager'
[camera1/realsense2_camera_manager-2] process has died [pid 3081, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=realsense2_camera_manager __log:=/home/jad/.ros/log/8900c75c-db4b-11e8-899e-e4a471c99bc7/camera1-realsense2_camera_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/jad/.ros/log/8900c75c-db4b-11e8-899e-e4a471c99bc7/camera1-realsense2_camera_manager-2*.log
[camera1/realsense2_camera-3] process has died [pid 3082, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory realsense2_camera_manager __name:=realsense2_camera __log:=/home/jad/.ros/log/8900c75c-db4b-11e8-899e-e4a471c99bc7/camera1-realsense2_camera-3.log].
log file: /home/jad/.ros/log/8900c75c-db4b-11e8-899e-e4a471c99bc7/camera1-realsense2_camera-3*.log
```

Edit :

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 039: ID 8086:0b07 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 038: ID 8086:0b07 Intel Corp.   
Bus 002 Device 037: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.
```

lsusb -t:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 37, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 38, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 38, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 38, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 38, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 38, If 4, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 4, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 54, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 45, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 45, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 53, If 0, Class=Imaging, Driver=usbfs, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306963/cannot-launch-2-realsense-camera-d435-on-one-pc-(solved-)/) by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2018-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-29**:\

> failed Last Error: Device or resource busy

I don't use any realsense hw myself, but this error seems to indicate that both driver instances are trying to open the same device.

You'll probably need to figure out some way to configure the driver instances to open different cameras.

**Comment by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) on 2018-10-29**:
Did you update the realsense ROS wrapper and which launch file are you using?
Could you please provide us with the output of `lsusb` and `lsusb -t` while having both cameras connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A couple things to check:

1. Are you using the "rs_multiple_devices" launch file?
2. Did you put the right serial numbers in the launch file? A sticker on the camera shows the serial number.
3. Are you using USB3 ports?

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on 2018-10-29**:
@AndyZe Thanks !! I just made it work.  was launching the rs_multiple_devices without filling the serial numbers coz I though this will be automatically assigned once I run the launch file so it seemed that I was launching the same camera twice. Now it is working with the correct serial numbers.